# Obfuscated stack traces in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-r8

Anyone here who has had problems with Firebase Crashlytics and R8 obfuscation? I keep getting obfuscated stacktraces in the console. It seems like the `mapping.txt` file is correctly uploaded to the Crashlytics API when building the app:

```
2023-09-08T10:46:40.132+0200 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request PUT /v1/project/-/app/[redacted]/upload/java/[redacted] HTTP/1.1
2023-09-08T10:46:40.132+0200 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2023-09-08T10:46:40.132+0200 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2023-09-08T10:46:41.794+0200 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2023-09-08T10:46:41.795+0200 [DEBUG] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] PUT response: [reqId=null] 200
2023-09-08T10:46:41.796+0200 [INFO] [com.google.firebase.crashlytics] Mapping file uploaded: [redacted]/build/outputs/mapping/qa/mapping.txt
2023-09-08T10:46:41.796+0200 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] 
2023-09-08T10:46:41.796+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute uploadMappingFile for :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileQa'
2023-09-08T10:46:41.797+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Executing task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileQa''
2023-09-08T10:46:41.738+0200 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
2023-09-08T10:46:41.738+0200 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileQa
2023-09-08T10:46:41.796+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Execute uploadMappingFile for :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileQa' completed
2023-09-08T10:46:41.797+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Executing task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileQa'' completed
```

Also when using R8 Retrace locally with the mapping file and the stacktrace as downloaded from the Firebase Console it de-obfuscates without problems:

```
// this works fine and outputs the de-obfuscated stracktrace
./retrace [redacted]/app/build/outputs/mapping/qa/mapping.txt [redacted]/stack.txt
```

Any idea’s? It seems like Firebase doesn’t have the option to upload mapping files manually or view uploaded mapping files in the console anymore.

Comment: Are you getting all traces as obfuscated? Or only for a few? If getting for a few, you may need to add some additional rules for proguard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, I have had these problems with Firebase Crashlytics but in
> android studio electric eel 2022.1.1 the only solution I gave was to
> update my buil.grable module to a previous version and it worked for
> me, it doesn't help much but I hope it works for you.

```
       // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // firebase-crashlytics
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> // main module

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
//Firebase database
```